# Displaying a Specific Activity Without Displaying the Main Activity of the Application

Tags: android

I have an Intent which starts/open an activity/window that is triggered by an alarm. Everything works fine, however the Main activity/window of the Application is also open behind the first activity referenced above when triggered. Thus, when this activity is dismissed (with the help of a button), the Main window of the Application is displayed on the device. How can I open my activity without opening the Main activity of the Application? Basically, the user shound't be seeing the Main activity of the Application upon dismissing the activity triggered by the alarm. Please note that I am not explicitly calling the Main activity upon opening the specific activity mentioned above. Is this normal behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

The specific activity is launched with the following lines:

```
Intent intentRead = new Intent(context, myActivity.class);
intentRead.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(intentRead);
```

Comment: How exactly are you opening the Activity? Can you post your code?

Comment: I have added the few lines which actually starts the specific activity. Hopefully, that is enough.

Comment: Where is that being called?

Comment: In a BroadcastReceiver, which is called by an alarmmanager.

Comment: Is your app in the Recents menu before this is called? Without more code (like how `myActivity` is defined), it's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Your code starts a new Activity in a new task :

```
Intent intentRead = new Intent(context, myActivity.class); 
intentRead.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(intentRead);
```

The Flags make sure that the new activity gets its own task and the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Now, suppose your MainActivity is already in the background(recent apps) and alarm is triggered which starts your myActivity. If no instance of myActivity is present then a second task is created for it. Else if an instance is present then the all activities on top of myActivity in the second task will be removed.

---

**Solution**

In your case, as you want to clear any other activities present you should use :

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

> [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: Wonderful! This solution has indeed solved my issue. Thank you J'' for your time and answer. J

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `first` activity is started by your main activity, could you just finish main activity after starting the `first` activity. I mean like this:

```
startActivity(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.finish();
```